# Do I need to unsubscribe from timer(1000)?

Tags: angular, rxjs

If I create a `timer()` with one execution like:

```
timer(1000).subscribe(() => console.log("some logging"));
```

do I need to unsubscribe?

The docs say:

> If period is not specified, the output Observable emits only one value

so, as far as i learned about `RxJS` yet, I guess, that `timer()` might be completed after the execution. But I am not quite sure. There is not marble diagram, which shows an completed `timer()`.

**NOTE**

I am **not** asking about *how* to unsubscribe; I need to know if a `timer()` without a given period completes and does not need to be unsubscribed.

Comment: Before asking question, did you consider to actually **test** it ;) I mean, you are using `console.log`, so you can establish it yourself with just that, if the docs aren't clear enough :)

Comment: but how could I test this? The console.log obviously logs _1_ time, and then? How could I check, that the handler is removed?

Comment: subscribe() takes 3 arguments. The third one is the completion callback. If it's called, it means the observable has completed. If it has completed, then the subscribers are unsubscribed.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks, I forgot the third subscribe parameter.

Comment: FYI, `subscribe` also optionally takes an 'Observer' object with `next`, `error`, and `complete` properties:

const myObserver = {
  next: console.log,
  error: console.error,
  complete: () => console.log('complete')
};

`.subscribe(myObserver)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It will complete since you are not providing the second argument "period".

Here is the documentation http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-timer

Here is an example exposing the error and complete in the subscription https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-timer-test?file=index.ts

I hope that is helpful

Comment: Thanks for the reminder of the third subscribe parameter! I did not think of this one.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question on the bases of the timer() documentation, which is a bit confusing if you do not read it carefully and in full, at it is initially stating:

*... that emits an infinite sequence of ascending integers,...*

Regardless, the answer to the question is NO, you do not have to unsubscribe as demonstrated by the accepted answer.

I wanted to offer here a little trick, (if you are unsure, in hurry or get lazy or sloppy understanding your rsjx tools), but still want to make sure, your subscriptions unsubscribe, you could use:

```
yourObservable.pipe(take(1)).subscribe( . . . // your action(s) //
```

The piped take(1) will close the subscription for you.

Comment: Thank you, for your input. I used the trick with `take` when converting an observable to a promise (let's not talk about, why this is necessary). Without this, these observables do also not complete.